# Error using bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2

Im trying use the command `bin/magento setup:upgrade` in magento 2.1.2 on macOS but the terminal show this error:

`Parse error: parse error in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93`

How can solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned line contains a splat operator which unpacks values from the array into the list of method arguments:

```
return new $type(...array_values($args));
```

If you are getting parse error there, it may be that you use too old PHP version.

Check what version you have installed by running this command in the terminal:

```
php -v
```

The minimal supported version for Magento 2.1.2 is PHP 5.6.5:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-2.1-tech.html

You need to upgrade PHP on your local environment and it should work then.

Comment: Im using PHP 7 the most recent in MAMP

Comment: @victor thanks, could you show output of "php -v" command mentioned in my answer?